# .map() not a function within reduce()

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
map(res => {
    const finalRows = res.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return [
        ...acc,
        ...curr.map(row => ({
          ...row,
          chevron: ' ',
        }))
      ]
    }, []);
.....
```

'res' looks like an array of objects, those objects being rows. Using reduce(), it should return an array, but I am using map to go through each of the current rows and adding a 'chevron' column. I feel like maybe it doesn't know it's returning an array yet and treating it like an object still, therefore I'm getting the error 'curr.map not a function', however, I'm not sure if that is the real issue. Any ideas?

Comment: You can call `map` on an array. You are calling it on an item in the array (within the `reduce` function). If you want to add `chevron` as a field to each item you could replace that call with `curr.chevron = '';` See also [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: The purpose of the reduce function is to (ha!) reduce the array to a *single element*. If your array is an array of objects, it will return an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a deeper look at your code:

- As you said, `res` is an array of objects
- The second argument of `.reduce`'s callback is the current item in the provided array
- So `curr` is an item of `res`

But here, it seems that `curr` isn't an array but instead another type of object (like JSON), which is why you're getting this error.

It would only have worked if `res` had been an array of arrays, as `.map` cannot be called on non-array objects.

Also, another way of writing your code in a more simple way is:

```
// For each row of the `res` array...
res.map(row => {
  // Clone it, so the new row isn't linked to the existing one
  const newRow = row.slice(0);
  // Set its 'chevron' property
  newRow.chevron = ' ';
  // Return the new row
  return newRow;
}); // Here we get the new array of objects
```